# Purpose of a pH Problem

Tags: acid-base, ph

I was doing a multiple choice question as follows.

The pH scale measures the

1. Strength of an acid
2. Concentration of hydrogen ions
3. Strength of hydrogen ions
4. Concentration of an acid

The answer is 2 but why is 1 not sufficient. The way I understand the pH scale is that it measures how acidic or alkaline a substance is. So does it not measure the strength of an acid?

Comment: Low concentration of stronger (like sulfuric) acid can have higher pH than high concentration  of weaker (like acetic) acid.

Comment: @Poutnik Could you explain that statement briefly? Why is this the case?

Comment: Concentration of H+ ions and therefore pH depends on acid concentration (as their source) and degree of their production (depending on acid strength).

Comment: Strength ≠ concentration for acids and bases. A stronger acid has a lower pKa, regardless of concentration. I think the confusion comes from the colloquial use of "strong/strength" to refer to relative concentrations.

Answer (score 3):

pH is approximated as $\mathrm{-log\ce{[H+]}}$. It specifically has the $\ce{[H+]}$ or concentration of $\ce{H+}$ term, so pH is a direct measure of that.

$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is a better measure of the strength of an acid. Some acids are stronger than others, and dissociate more in water. While, yes, more acidic species produce more $\ce{H+}$ ions, thus having lower pH, there isn't a fully direct relationship.

Comment: Rather pH=f(acid concentration, acid strength)

Comment: pH is not defined as $-\log[\ce{H+}],$ rather as $-\log a(\ce{H+}).$ See https://doi.org/10.1351/pac198557030531. Note the [proper typesetting for $\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7347).

Comment: @andselisk While that is truth, sometimes simplified truth is more helpful at certain education levels. Like W=F.l in elementary school, later vec F . vec l in high school, later int(vec F . vec dL) in college/university. // E.g. standard school formulas for pH almost never deal with activities.

Comment: @Poutnik Fine, but then don't lie by saying "*defined as*", at least say "*approximated as*". Yes, I'm aware of [eigenchris — What Is Momentum? (joke video)](https://youtu.be/jm7jVi8akcc).

Comment: @andselisk Imperative don't lie assumes lying, what is not confirmed. I have not said such a thing.

Comment: @andselisk Good point, I've only dealt with activity coefficient a few times and just got too used to that 'approximated' form for pH.

Comment: @andselisk But as a figure of speech I agree.  BTW a nice video.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have two different aqueous solutions, one being a strong acid and the other being a weak acid:

$$\ce{HCl(aq)<=>H+(aq) +Cl-(aq)},\quad \pu{K_a}=10^6$$

$$\ce{HCOOH(aq)<=>H+(aq) +COOH-(aq)},\quad \pu{K_a}=10^{-3.75}$$

The strength of an acid is a measure of to what extent it is dissociated into its constituent ions. The dissociation fraction $\alpha$ gives us an idea of this, and it is defined as:

$$\alpha=\frac{x}{C_{\pu{Ao}}}$$

Where $x$ represents the equilibrium concentrations of $\ce{H^+}$ ions or conjugate base $\ce{B-}$ ions, assuming no initial amounts of either are present, and we can make the approximation:

$$\pu{pH}=\pu{-log}\;{C_{\ce{H^+}}}\implies x=10^{\pu{-pH}}$$

The initial concentration $C_{\pu{Ao}}$ can also be set in terms of $x$:

$$\pu{K_a}=\frac{x^2}{C_{\pu{Ao}}-x}\implies C_{\pu{Ao}}=\frac{x^2}{\pu{K_a}}+x$$

Substituting in $\alpha$:

$$\alpha=\frac{10^{\pu{-pH}}}{\frac{10^{\pu{-2pH}}}{\pu{K_a}}+10^{\pu{-pH}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{10^{\pu{-pH}}}{\pu{K_a}}+1}$$

We can observe that:

$$\pu{K_a}\to\infty\implies \alpha\to1$$

$$\pu{K_a}\to0\implies \alpha\to0$$

If we plot $\alpha$ vs $pH$ for $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HCOOH}$, we get:

[image]

Now, let's suppose someone were to hand you an aqueous solution of an unknown acid with a known $\pu{pH}$ value of 2.

You might be tempted to conclude that since the $\pu{pH}$ is low, the acid must be a strong acid like $\ce{HCl}$ that is completely dissociated ($\alpha=1$); however, as shown in the plot, it could very well be a weak acid like $\ce{HCOOH}$ that is partially dissociated ($\alpha=0.017$).

In other words, $\pu{pH}$ alone is not a reliable criterion for gauging the strength of an acid. If it is coupled with $\pu{K_a}$ however, it can be.